# Find the object key that's not used in a replace function

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a replace function that takes the values from an object and replaces the template literals like this:

```js
let componentJSON = [
  { "template": "<div class='${layout} ${border}'></div>" },
  {
    "layout": "grid",
    "color": "blue",
    "border": "primary"
  }
];

const template = componentJSON[0].template
const classes = componentJSON[1]

let html = template.replace(/\$\{(.*?)\}/g, (match, key) => classes[key]);

console.log(html);
```

Is it possible to then return (or consoleLog) the object key that wasn't used? In this case "color": "blue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could delete the property from the object, then examine what remains in the object at the end.

```js
let componentJSON = [
  { "template": "<div class='${layout} ${border}'></div>" },
  {
    "layout": "grid",
    "color": "blue",
    "border": "primary"
  }
];

const template = componentJSON[0].template
const classes = componentJSON[1]

const html = template.replace(
  /\$\{(.*?)\}/g,
  (match, key) => {
    const str = classes[key];
    delete classes[key];
    return str;
  }
);

console.log(componentJSON[1]);
```

Comment: To ask a probably much more complex part 2, I then want to rerun the replace function with what's left - because "layout" might = "${color}" - is there a way to do that in the same function? Maybe recursively?

Comment: If you're sure the object will be completely exhausted, sure, just perform the same operation until no keys are left (either recursively or with a loop)

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the keys used then filter them from the original key set

```js
let componentJSON = [
  { "template": "<div class='${layout} ${border}'></div>" },
  {
    "layout": "grid",
    "color": "blue",
    "border": "primary"
  }
];

const [ { template }, classes ] = componentJSON;

const usedKeys = new Set();
let html = template.replace(/\$\{(.*?)\}/g, (match, key) => 
  (usedKeys.add(key), classes[key]));

console.log(html);

const unused = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(classes).filter(([ key ]) => !usedKeys.has(key))
);

console.log("unused", unused);
```